# How do i shift the value of specific row in a table to other page

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am trying to select one row in a table and move it other page

i have table

```
|start            |end               |

|2019/2/22 9:00 pm|2019/2/22 10:00 pm|
```

my code is

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="start">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Start </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element.start}}
    </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="end">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.end}}
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="session()">
            Join Meeting
        </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

my .ts code is

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getTrueBook()
        .subscribe(res = > {
            console.log(res);
            this.meetings = res;
        }, err = > {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What exactly do you want to shift? The data? The template?

Comment: @WillAlexander i want to shift the data inside table to another page

Comment: Have you tried passing the data to a service?